# Mac App Store Login Problem

Tags: mac-appstore

Since I upgraded my MacBook to Mountain Lion I have the following problem: in the Mac App Store it's not possible to log in or to buy/download anything. Clicking on log in just doesn't do anything, no error massage. What to do?

Edit: The following error messages are in the log file after trying to download some app:

```
08/11/12 20:36:57.171 -[ISStoreURLOperation _runURLOperation] - load the URL from the bag if needed
08/11/12 20:36:57.172 url:http://ax.init.itunes.apple.com/bag.xml?ix=5  bagKey:(null)
08/11/12 20:36:57.173 -[ISStoreURLOperation _runURLOperation]: _addStandardQueryParametersForURL: http://ax.init.itunes.apple.com/bag.xml?ix=5
08/11/12 20:36:57.179 ISURLBag: Insufficient data to parse URL bag
08/11/12 20:36:57.181 ISStoreURLOperation: Chose not to retry after error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "Unknown Error." UserInfo=0x7f8cbb060600 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown Error.}
08/11/12 20:36:57.182 -[ISStoreURLOperation _runURLOperation] - load the URL from the bag if needed
08/11/12 20:36:57.182 url:http://phobos.apple.com/bag.xml?ix=5  bagKey:(null)
08/11/12 20:36:57.182 -[ISStoreURLOperation _runURLOperation]: _addStandardQueryParametersForURL: http://phobos.apple.com/bag.xml?ix=5
08/11/12 20:36:57.188 ISURLBag: Insufficient data to parse URL bag
08/11/12 20:36:57.189 ISStoreURLOperation: Chose not to retry after error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "Unknown Error." UserInfo=0x7f8cbb062270 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown Error.}
08/11/12 20:36:57.189 ISAuthenticationChallengeOperation: Could not load URL bag: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "Unknown Error." UserInfo=0x7f8cbb062270 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown Error.}
08/11/12 20:36:57.190 AuthenticateOperation: Authentication challenge failed: Error Domain=ISErrorDomain Code=-128 "Unknown Error." UserInfo=0x7f8cbb031150 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown Error.}
08/11/12 20:36:57.192 StorePurchaseBatchOperation: Canceling 1 purchases after failure: Error Domain=ISErrorDomain Code=-128 "Unknown Error." UserInfo=0x7f8cbb031150 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown Error.}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figurred what the problem was. Hands Off was blocking the internet access for some appstore related process. Very annoying that the app store doesn't show any error message if the internet is not available.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that you can try repair the disk permissions in Disk Utility. Might be a problem with some files.

Do you get the actual login prompt or just nothing happens? Do the content in the store load?

Comment: I'll try repairing disk permissions. No login prompt, just no reaction. After clicking buy on some item the button turns grey again after 3 seconds.

Comment: Sounds odd. A repair and repair permissions sounds like a start anyway.

Comment: Repairing disk permission didn't help. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I actually had a similar issue the other day, I think. When you try to download something, it asks for your username and password again and again? I ended up resetting my password several times before I contacted Apple Support, and got this response:

> Hello Terrance,
>
> Thank you for your quick response and for providing us the requested
>   information.
>
> I'm sorry you ran into an error when you tried to use the iTunes and
>   App Store. This error was caused by a temporary issue with the iTunes
>   and App Store that should be resolved now. Please check the iTunes and
>   App Store again after 24 hours. All features should be working well.
>
> If you still encounter the same problem after 24 hours, please reply
>   to this email and let us know.  I'll be happy to assist your further.

Sure enough, the next time I tried to make a purchase, it went through just fine.

Try contacting Apple Support to make them aware of the problem, and you should get squared away.

Comment: No when I try to download something there is no log in prompt. The buy button just turns grey again.